# Android - always return to currently active activity from notification?

Tags: android, android-activity, notifications

I currently have a Tab screen in my application. I use a notification to notify the user of a state change in my application and in normal circumstances when the user clicks on the notification it will return to this tab screen.

Here is the code I use for this:

```
        String ns = Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE;
        mNotificationManager = (NotificationManager) context.getSystemService(ns);

        Intent notificationIntentRegState = new Intent();
        ComponentName cn = new ComponentName(context, TabScreenActivity.class);
        notificationIntentRegState.setComponent(cn);

        contentIntentRegState = PendingIntent.getActivity(context, 0, notificationIntentRegState, 0);
        notificationRegStateText = context.getString(R.string.app_name);
        notificationRegState = new Notification(icon, notificationRegStateText, 0);

        notificationRegState.setLatestEventInfo(context, notificationRegStateText, context.getString(R.string.notification_text, contentIntentRegState);
        mNotificationManager.notify(3, notificationRegState);
```

However in my application the user can start another activity from the TabScreen and when this activity is "active" I want the notification to bring the user to the new activity and not the tabscreen activity. But when the notification is clicked it always goes to the Tab screen.

Is it possible to make sure the notification always directs the user to the most recent activity?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could recreate the last activity that has been created by user, in response to notification beeing clicked.

in your pending activity, you could add an extra data to remmeber which activity to show :

```
Intent notificationIntentRegState = new Intent( "showTabScreen" );
ComponentName cn = new ComponentName(context, TabScreenActivity.class);
notificationIntentRegState.setComponent(cn);
notificationIntentRegState.putExtra( CURRENT_ACTIVITY, getCurrentActivityId() );
```

where getCurrrentActivityID() returnin a constant that you use to identify the last activity launched.

And, in the onCreateMethod of your tabScreen, you could check the intent that you received and the extra param to launch that activity again in response to a click on notification

```
@Override
public void onCreate( Bundle b )
{
     String action = getIntent().getAction();
     if( action != null && action.equals( "showTabScreen" )  )
     {
        int activityToShow = getIntent().getIntExtra( CURRENT_ACTIVITY, -1 );
        if( activityToShow != -1 )
        {
           switch( activityToShow )
           {
               case ACTIVITY_ID_ONE : startActivity( ActivityOne.class );
           }//switch
           startActivity();
        }//if
     }//if
}//met
```

With, of course, you tabScreen filtering the intent name "*showTabScreen*" in your manifest.xml file.

Regards,
 Stéphane

Comment: I've tried this method however when I use it a new Activity gets started rather than the old one being brought back to the foreground

Comment: @Donal Rafferty you want showTabScreen to show up but not new ones ? So maybe you should have another intent action name (I mean both in manifest.xml) that explicitly launches nothing from showTabScreen...

Comment: I don't want the TabScreeen to show at all, there will be another activity active, this will be the last activity the user was interacting with, when the user presses home they will be able to get back into my app via notification. This notification currently returns to the Tabscreen but should return to the active activity and not the tabscreen.

Comment: @Donal Rafferty Oh ! I finally understood your problem (I think) : when user push the HOME button, they go back to a brand new activity : a new instance of the activity that was launched before. It's the right activity class, but not the right instance. Is that it ?

If so, it's hope less : android controls which activity is kept in memory and which one has to be recreated. So, the best you can do is to save every param that you need to RECREATE the activity as it was, and not hope that android will have kept the last instance and display it again, as it will never happen.